# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert' - Tentando inserir uma coluna

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Bom dia ! Sou novo em python e estou tentando montar um script que apague algumas linhas e inclua uma coluna em um dataframe só que por algum motivo que eu não consigo entender ele retorna esse erro.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('planilha.xlsx, sheet_name=1)

df = df.drop(['ID EMPRESA', 'NF 2', 'VALOR NF 2', 'VAT'], axis=1)

df = df.drop(df[df.TPV == 0.00].index, inplace=True)

df = df.insert(loc=25, column='Crédito BOAC', value=None)

df.head()


removido por seg.

Como eu deveria fazer neste caso?
```

Comment: coloque na dúvida um exemplo do seu dataset, mas esse erro é quando o tipo do objeto é `None`. Como seu dataset da pra testar onde ocorreu o erro e o motivo.

Comment: Imonferrari, editei

Comment: O erro acontece na chamada de `to_excel`, mas no seu código ele nem é utilizado. Tem certeza que colocou o código correto ou ele por completo?

Comment: Pelo erro mostra que você está chamando uma função de um objeto `None`, provavelmente no meio do caminho aconteceu algo com esse objeto que ele ficou como `None`.

Comment: Woss eu tinha colocado # no ```insert``` pra ver se o restante ia, por isso o erro estava no ```to_excel```. Corrigido, mas o erro persiste rs.

Comment: Imonferrari, então, eu entendi isso também, mas não sei como corrigir ou em qual momento isso aconteceu.

Comment: insira todo o código e disponibiliza os dados(pode remover os dados sigilosos caso tenha).
Qualquer coisa faz o upload do arquivo de dados em algum serviço de nuvem e posta o link aqui.

Comment: No segundo `drop`, você definiu `inplace=True`. Isso fará com que o `drop` ocorra direto sobre o próprio `df`, retornando `None`. Se deseja obter o retorno, remova o parâmetro `inplace`.

Comment: Não está funcionando. Eu retirei o ```inplace=True``` mas o erro persiste.

Comment: Imonferrar, segue os links:
script:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W0OZFMoBOKbS2IxiB3UtySmCMBgJcAlw/view?usp=sharing
excel:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qV1lxJ0idIo6iI6_FqQayYeUe5Vf9Wmu/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Você deve alterar disso:

```
df = df.drop(df[df.TPV == 0.00].index, inplace=True)

df = df.insert(loc=25, column='Crédito BOAC', value=None)
```

Para isso:

```
df = df.drop(df[df.TPV == 0.00].index)

df.insert(loc = 21, column = 'Crédito BOAC', value = None)
```

o insert já altera seu data frame sem precisar fazer uma copia pra dentro dele mesmo.

Caso queira usar o inplace = True:

```
df.drop(df[df.TPV == 0.00].index, inplace = True)

df.insert(loc = 21, column = 'Crédito BOAC', value = None)
```

Comment: Deu certo ! Você é demais ! Obrigado cara.

Comment: Por nada! Abraço!